# Compute Weighted Profit Total for Each Item Sold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working through some sales data in Pandas and I'm attempting to find the most profitable item (We sell a range of various items), but this is weighted in order to truely find the item that generates the most profit. This may be a NumPy question. The equation looks like this:

```
    (Individual Item Total Profit) * ((Number of that Item Sold / Total Items Sold))
```

I attempted to write a function that computes the weighted avg profit made based on the above equation:

```
    def w_avg(df, profit, item_type):
    total_profit = df.groupby(profit).sum(item_type)
    num_indiv_sold = df.groupby(item_type).count()
    total_all_sold = df.groupby(item_type).count().sum()
    return (total_profit * (num_indiv_sold / total_all_sold))
```

Here's what I'm after:

```
    Sample Input:
    Item Type          Profit  
    MacBook Pro        205
    Macbook Air        430
    Dell Inspiron      175
    HP                 125
    Dell Inspiron      315
    HP                 115
    MacBook Pro        410
    Macbook Air        225
    Dell Inspiron      135
    HP                 115

    Computations for MacBook Pro:
    (205 + 410) * (2 / 10) = 123

    Output:
    Item Type           
    MacBook Pro        123
    ...                ...
```

Then call the function with the col names:

```
    df.groupby('Item Type').apply(w_avg, 'Profit', 'Item Type')
```

This function does not do what I need it to as I'm sure you can tell. I basically need to return a col with all the item types and they're appropriate weighted profits. I wasn't sure if I needed to loop over the item types, as I was hoping my function would return all item types anyway (as most pandas functions seem to). Hopefully someone can help! Super new with Pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `groupby()` and `sum()` and `count()` method:

```
g=df.groupby('Item Type',sort=False)
out=g['Profit'].sum()*(g['Profit'].count()/len(df))
#Since the sum of total counts is equal to the length of df so we are using len(df)
#OR
#g['Profit'].sum()*(g['Profit'].count()/g['Profit'].count().sum())
```

output of `out`:

```
Item Type
MacBook Pro      123.0
Macbook Air      131.0
Dell Inspiron    187.5
HP               106.5
Name: Profit, dtype: float64
```

**Note:** you can also use `agg()` method for example:

```
out=g['Profit'].agg('sum')*(g['Profit'].agg('count')/len(df))
```